# Adding usings inside the namespace

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Is there a way to configure [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to add using references to a file within the appropriate namespace?

Currently it adds them to the top of the file, which is fine, until you want multiple namespaces in the same file.

For example, I would like it to be like the following:

```
namespace A
{
    using System;

    // other classes
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Options > Code Editing > C# > Namespace Imports:

Insert using directives when necessary > Add using directive to the deepest scope.

[image: Namespace Imports]

Comment: Thanks, the screenshot was very helpful too.

Comment: On my machine, it wasn't in these options but I searched for "Deepest scope" and found where it got moved . (Personally it was in C# > Syntax Style)

Answer (score 3):

Just to bring an up to date answer here as I was wanting to do this but not having R# (ReSharper) installed...

Its now available from Visual Studio 2019 directly since the [16.1 Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.1#net-productivity).

I found this on [developercommunity.visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/847161/add-setting-to-place-using-always-inside-namespace.html)

> The code style to include using directives inside or outside a namespace was added in Visual Studio 2019 update 16.1. You can now set your preference in Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style or in an EditorConfig file and the IDE can apply it through messages, warnings, or errors depending on the severity you specify in the code style rule